# Can we install teradata express on GCP compute instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradata-covalent

I'm trying to work out a way to install teradata express on GCP compute instance or any other GCP compute service?? any leads would be appreciated.. thank you..!!

Comment: Teradata on GCP is not yet publicly available, only AWS and Azure.

Comment: not talking about custom images, like can i install teradata from https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player

on any of linux machine like centos or ubuntu??

Comment: Teradata runs on SLES (Suse Enterprise Linux) only

Comment: There is a VMWare Workstation Player for Linux so in theory you might be able to install that on one of the GCP instances that supports [Nested Virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) and run the Teradata Express VM within that. But with two levels of virtualization and the already limited Express configuration, it may not be worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

[Teradata Express for VMware Player](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player) is provided as a pre-configured VMware virtual machine based on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (SLES11). It supposes **VMware Player** or **VMware Server** as an execution environment.

Inside of the downloaded package there is a VMX file. This is the primary configuration file, which stores settings chosen in the New Virtual Machine Wizard or virtual machine settings editor. See [VMware: What Files Make Up a Virtual Machine?](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html)

SLES version 11 is **not supported on GCE** so you can't install Teradata Express on GCP "as is".  See [Compute Engine > Documentation > Supported operating systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment#supported-os)

If you really need to get the Teradata Express for VMware Player working on GCE you should upgrade the SLES11 VM to **SLES12** or **SLES15** on VMware Player, and then import this VM into GCE.

[Updating and Upgrading SUSE Linux Enterprise › Upgrading SUSE Linux Enterprise](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-update-sle.html)

[Upgrading to SUSE® Linux Enterprise 12 > SLE11 to SLE12 Migration](https://www.suse.com/media/presentation/TUT88423_upgrading_suse_linux_enterprise_server_11__suse_linux_enterprise_server_12.pdf)

While upgrading from SLES11 to SLES12 you should keep in mind that [**UEFI** bootloaders are **not supported**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#limitations) in GCE for imported disks.

Having got Teradata Express on SLES12, you can consider two ways for import.

**1.** **Create a new VM instance** on GCE and use a pre-configured virtual disk with Teradata on SLES12 for creation of a boot disk image. The import tool supports most virtual disk file formats, including VMDK, VHD, and RAW. For more information, see [Compute Engine > Documentation > Importing virtual disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks).

**2.** **Import a VM in OVF format** into Compute Engine accordingly with [Compute Engine > Documentation > Importing virtual appliances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files). The source VM could be whether in an **OVF** package or in an **OVA** single file. To convert VMware VMX to OVF or OVA you can use [Open Virtualization Format Tool (ovftool)](https://code.vmware.com/web/tool/4.4.0/ovf). Please see [OVF Tool User Guide](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf20/ovftool_201_userguide.pdf) for more details.

Both of these methods look a bit more complicated when you consider that Google provides its own data warehouse solutions: you could consider migration from Teradata to BigQuery so that use native solution provided and (what's important) supported by Google.

[BigQuery Data Transfer Service > Documentation > Migrating data from Teradata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration)

[Solutions > Migrating data warehouses to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/dw-bq-migration-overview)

Comment: I doubt you can simply upgrade the SLES11 within the TDExpress, there will be lots of dependencies in the Teradata packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Vantage Express on GCP using nested virtualization. Here is the official how-to document: https://quickstarts.teradata.com/vantage.express.gcp.html.